# Location of saved images from Facebook Messenger app

Tags: facebook-messenger

I don't use Facebook app (browsed on Google Chrome), but I use its Messenger app. Where can I find the saved images from Facebook Messenger app?

Comment: Do you use Facebook messenger app or Google Chrome to access facebook? Are you able to see the saved photos into your phone's Gallery?

Answer (score 12):

Facebook Messenger saves photos to `$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/Pictures/Messenger`.  That variable depends on your device, but on mine it is `/storage/sdcard0` which is also pointed to by the `/sdcard` symlink.

Comment: Is there any way to change that? I don't want syncthing to sync all the gifs I get sent.

Comment: `Computer\SAMSUNG-SGH-I537\Phone\Pictures\Messenger` is where they appeared with a USB cable to my Windows 7 desktop.

Comment: This helped, but it would also be great to provide a  contextual reference (like version numbers or documentation link) in case this changes.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson This answer is nearly 9 years old, so I'm not sure what the app version was back then.  Feel free to report your version here, if it still works.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Chrome Browser then you can view it in your Downloads folder. If you are using Facebook Messenger App then you should be able to view the photos in you Gallery app. Internally when using Facebook messenger, it hides the downloaded photos inside the system. You have to have a rooted phone to access those hidden files. Its in the hidden root directory,

```
data/data/com.facebook.orca/cache
```

you have to copy the folder to a directory and rename the `.image` files to `.jpg` files.

Comment: Can I not take ADB backup (no root) of this facebook app and then extract it to see these images?

Comment: @Firelord Yes that can be another way but the OP's question title asks "where can I find the saved images.." so that's why I mentioned the path to access it