# What is the Location of Saved Images from the Facebook App?

Tags: file-system, photos, facebook, media-files

What is the location of saved images from the Facebook app? I found this [Location of saved images from Facebook Messenger app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110648/location-of-saved-images-from-facebook-messenger-app) but I'm interested in photos from the Facebook app itself

Answer (score 1):

Images from the Facebook app are saved in $EXTERNAL_STORAGE/DCIM/Facebook/